# MvvmCross 4 and Xamarin.iOS -> How to load viewcontroller from Core when using Storyboards?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xcode-storyboard

I have updated to mvvmcross 4.   I am using storyboards and can't make the controllers be initiated by the viewmodel (pcl).

Does someone have a sample? I found a sample on mvvmcross page but they use xib, it wont work properly when using storyboards.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `MvxFromStoryboard` attribute, as shown here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45253/cross-platform-development-with-mvvmcross

```cs
// Will look for a UIViewController with identifier "MyView" inside a Storyboard named "MyView.storyboard"
[MvxFromStoryboard]
public class MyView : MvxViewController
{
    public MyView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {}
}

// Will look for a UIVIewController with identifier "MyOtherViewInSameStoryboard" inside a Storyboard named "MyView.storyboard"
[MvxFromStoryboard(StoryboardName = "MyView")]
public class MyOtherViewInSameStoryboard : MvxViewController
{
    public MyOtherViewInSameStoryboard(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {}
}
```

The `ViewModel` is connected to the `ViewController` via a naming Convention.

**XYZ**ViewModel ~> **XYZ**ViewController